# Loading view from NIB returns zero frame view - what to do?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller, it is creating another view controlling and adding resulting view to its subview. But the problem is that the view is getting created with frame (0, 0, 0, 0).

If I set the frame manually it is ok, but I don't want to set frame manually, I want autoresizing. Here is the code:

```
GridViewController *gridVC = [[GridViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GridView" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:gridVC];
[self.view addSubview:gridVC.view];
```

`self.view` has normal frame, and `gridVc.view` has (0,0,0,0) frame;

In xib I have couple of views, View is connected correctly, file owner is set correctly and everything looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing view controller containment like this (btw, I hope you also have your [`didMoveToParentViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didMoveToParentViewController%3a) call in there, too), I always set the `frame`, e.g.

```
gridVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Admittedly, I'm often adding my child view to a container which doesn't take up the whole screen, so it's critical in that situation, but, still, I'm not sure why you're reticent to just set the `frame`.

Once you do that, assuming you set your autosizing masks properly, everything will automatically resize for you as appropriate.

FYI, Apple sets the `frame` when they add the child's view in their example code, too (see [Listing 14-1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13)).

Obviously, if you use auto layout, you'd be setting the constraints (or using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`), but the idea is the same.

Comment: I am fine with setting frames, I used this approach, but setting frames for everything for every position and every rotation overwhelmed me quickly, so I decided to go with autoresizing route.

Comment: @Dvole - Definitely. Once you have all the autosizing masks set right, you only have to set this one `frame` and everything else is taken care of for you. .